# Relationship between elements in an internal direct product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> **Question**: 
>   Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of a group $G$.
>   If $G=HK$ and $g=h\bar {k} $, where $h\in G $ and $\bar {k} $. 
>   Is there any relationship among $|g|$, $|h|$ and $|\bar {k}|$?
>   What if $G=H\times K$?

Here's my attempt:

Suppose the order of $g$ is $n$.
So that $g^{n}=e$.
Now, $g^{n}=(h\bar {k})^{n}=h^{n}\bar {k}^{n}$.

It doesn't seem to be correct since nothing is mentioned about the group being finite. 
Any useful hint is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you write $\overline{k}$ instead of $k$? It's also not true that $(hk)^n = h^n k^n$ (if that's what you meant to write).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no in general. However, if $G$ is a direct product of $H$ and $K$, the elements of $H$ and $K$ commute pairwise, so the relation $g^n = (hk)^n = h^n k^n$ does hold. Moreover, the decomposition $G = HK$ is unique. Therefore, in a direct product:

- If $o(g) = n$, then $1 = g^n = h^n k^n$, so that $1 = h^n = k^n$. Therefore $o(h)$ and $o(k)$ both divide $o(g)$.
- If $o(h) = n$ and $o(k) = m$, then $o(g) = \operatorname{lcm}(n,m)$.

---

If $G = HK$ is not a direct product, you can't say much. For example, let $G$ be the nontrivial semidirect product of $\mathbb{Z}$ with $\mathbb{Z}/2$; we may describe $G$ explicitly as the free monoid on the letters $a,b$, made into a group under the constraints $a^{-1} = a$ and $b^{-1} = b$. Take $H = K = G$. Then $G = HK$, but the following can happen:

- If $h = ab$, $k=ba$, then both $h$ and $k$ have infinite order, but $o(hk) = 1$.
- If $h = ab$, $k = b$, then $h$ has infinite order, but $o(hk) = o(k) = 2$.

Comment: When you mentioned "direct product" , are you referring to the "external" or "internal" direct product?

Comment: @Mathematicing Internal in this case, as $H,K$ are subgroups of $G$.

Comment: As suspected. Thanks.